# Check for the first input text box in a webbrowser control

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

There's several input text boxes on the page and I want to find the first textbox in the page.

```
HtmlDocument doc = this.webBrowser1.Document;
var elements = doc.GetElementsByTagName("input");
foreach (HtmlElement element in elements)
{
   if (element.TabIndex == 0)
   {
      element.SetAttribute("value", "Value");
   }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You need to clarify here: are you using a `WebBrowser` control for example?

Comment: How are you ensuring that the elements variable are textboxes and not radio buttons, checkboxes, drop down lists, or other input elements?

Comment: what does "FIRST" input textbox really mean?

Comment: it seems like you should be able to just reference the first one in the elements collection. No need to examine the TabIndex property which probably isn't the right thing to do anyway

Comment: There's several input text boxes on the page and I want to find the first textbox in the page

Comment: Do you mean first from the top of HTML?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Using C# / JAvaScript

Comment: just fired that code at a page with multiple textboxes (none with tabindex set manually) and it worked perfectly.  i'd recommend stepping through it in the debugger to see why your document is behaving strangely (maybe all the controls have a non zero tabindex value?).

Comment: If I use that code all the text boxes get set with Value

Comment: can hidden inputs have a tabindex? just tried a variant using doc.GetElementsByTagName("input")[0].InnerText="Value"; and it hit a hidden input.  maybe that's what's happening with OP.

Comment: I tried that also didnt work for me

Comment: if your code is setting ALL inputs to the same value, am I going to get down voted for suggesting breaking out of the loop after setting the first value? but you need to make sure it's of the correct type (ie. not hidden or button, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

This skips past any hidden inputs - but it needs augmenting to skip over buttons, radiobuttons, etc.

```
        HtmlDocument doc = this.webBrowser1.Document;
        var elements = doc.GetElementsByTagName("input");
        foreach (HtmlElement element in elements)
        {
            if (!element.OuterHtml.ToLower().Contains("type=hidden"))
            {
                element.SetAttribute("value", "Value");
                break;
            }
        }
```